# How to "white out" old content while loading new with ajax?

Tags: ajax, loader, css

I  just made my first activity loader which I will display while loading a shipping_estimate.php file into the current file. What I also want to do is to have the old content covered with semitransparent white image and then have the loader on top of it.

I tried to set the semi transparent image as backround of the activity loader div, tried all combinations but the image always gets behind the loaded php.

Ajax function:

```
function load_shipping(str)
{   
var xmlhttp;
showLoader(); 
if (str.length==0)
  { 
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }

$(function() {
        $('#busy1').activity();
    });
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("shpquote").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    $(function() {
        $('#busy1').activity();     
    }); 
    }
  }

xmlhttp.open("GET","shipping_estimate.php?c="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

<?php echo "load_shipping($c);";
?>
</script>
```

This is where the content and loader is placed to. The class="trans_box1" means that it has semitransparent bg image set in CSS.

```
<table  align="right">
<tr>
<td>
<div id="busy1" class="trans_box1">
<div id="shpquote">
</div></div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I have never, not once got the image in top of shipping_estimate.php, alwais behind it, maybe because php is always loade after the image?

also tried this, doesn't work, loader is not visible at all.

```
<div id="shpquote" class="trans_box1;position:relative;width:300px;height:300px;" style="float:left">
<div  id="busy1" class="trans_box2" style="position:absolute;z-index:999; width:300px;height:300px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overcomplicating this a bit.. you already are using jquery so something easier might look like this:

```
function loadShipping() {
 //Show the loader here
 //maybe something like 
 $('#busy1').css({'opacity' : '1'});
 $.get('shipping_estimate.php?c='+str, {}, function(response) {
   //The response is handled here
   $('#shpquote').empty(); // clear the old stuff
   $('#shpquote').text(reply); //or something similar
   $('#busy1').css({'opacity' : '0'}); //hide the loader or overlay
 });
}
```

Hopefully this helps - there are lots of jQuery ajax examples on SO also.